# Can I convert a bash script into a Linux software?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm new to Linux and currently using Ubuntu14.04. I made a GUI based script for a specific purpose using bash. Now I actually want to convert it into a Linux software with some extra gui so that people can directly install it. How can I do that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you do not want to submit to the official repositories right now, you probably want to build a Debian (`.deb`) package (Ubuntu is based on Debian and uses that package format). Debian packages can be installed using the package manager of your choice or using `dpkg -i`.

If your software is written in Bash or any other language only matters as far as the steps for packaging may be a little different: For example, a C program has to be built (compiled and linked) before packaging, while a shell script is usually ready to be packed right away.

See [this wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging) for an introduction. Furthermore, the [debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) is "the" document for package development.

It is not a technical requirement, but if you want to build packages specifically for Ubuntu, you may want to read the [Ubuntu packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html) as well.